# oracle adf 11g EL comparison for partialTrigger not evaluating properly?

Tags: java, web, oracle-adf, oracle-ucm

Developing a page using Oracle ADF 11.1.1.9 (client requirement). On my page I have a selectOneChoice down with a list of subjects. Depending on which subject is chosen a partialTrigger is suppose to fire and load a jsff page that displays a list of pdf reports. It seems like code for the "render" is either not firing or the comparison is failing. Can someone see where my code is going wrong?

```
<af:panelTabbed id="pt20" 
   styleClass="AFStretchWidth" 
   dimensionsFrom="auto" childCreation="lazy"
   partialTriggers="soc2">
<af:showDetailItem text="BaggedMixes" id="sdi20" 
   styleClass="tabDetail" partialTriggers="soc2" 
   rendered="#{viewScope.SummaryReports.selecteReport} == 'BaggedMixes'" >
</af:showDetailItem>  
<af:showDetailItem text="Wrap" 
    id="sdi21" styleClass="tabDetail" 
    partialTriggers="soc2"
    rendered="#{viewScope.SummaryReports.selectedReport} == 'Wrap'">
</af:showDetailItem>  
</af:panelTabbed>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
rendered="#{viewScope.SummaryReports.selecteReport == 'BaggedMixes'}"
```

or

```
rendered="#{viewScope.SummaryReports.selecteReport eq 'BaggedMixes'}"
```

Timo